# utilizar fork em linux

Tags: c

Eu comecei a estudar a função `fork(2)` há pouco tempo e tentei criar um pequeno programa para calcular a soma de dois números. O algorítmo é feito para o processo filho receber dois valores enquanto o processo pai é responsável pelo cálculo.

O problema é que o valor das variáveis não está a passar de um lado para o outro. O código é o seguinte:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include <malloc.h>
static int d,p;
double pi;

int main(void)
{
int *m = malloc(10);
*m=1;
pid_t pid;

pid = fork();

if(pid == 0){
    printf("espera por dados (child)\n");
    scanf("%d",&p);
    *m=p;
    scanf("%d",&d);
    *(m+1)=d;
    exit(0);
}
else{
    pid = wait(NULL);
    pi=(double)p/(double)d;
}
printf("O valor da soma é %d",pi);
}
```

Alguém pode me explicar o que tem de errado com este código?

Answer (score 0):

Depois de um `fork()` os processos filho e pai virtualmente não compartilham mais a mesma área de memória. Para você fazer isso deve usar algum tipo de comunicação IPC. Se tudo o que você quer é transferir dois `int` do filho para o pai recomendo usar `pipe()` (procure por *"fork pipe"* no Google). Caso precise de uma transferência de dados mais sofisticada recomendo estudar os mecanismos IPC disponíveis no sistema operacional que você está usando.